# Part of XML doesn't shown

Tags: xml, xslt

I have such a XSL file. The first part of the XML file transform and shown in Internet Explorer without problem. But when I add the extra content at the end of the document it doesn't shown in Internet Explorer. The last part with `<Number>` tag doesn't shown. I don't know where is the problem.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<ClientList>
<xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">

<Client>
<IdNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</IdNumber>

<NameSurname>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' ' , Surname)"/>
</NameSurname>

</Client>
</xsl:for-each>
</ClientList>

<Number>
<xsl:value-of select="count(/ClientList/Client/ProductOwner[text()='true'])"/>
</Number>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClientList>
    <Client>
        <Name>Jan</Name>
        <Surname>Kowalski</Surname>
        <ProductOwner>true</ProductOwner>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <Name>Piotr</Name>
        <Surname>Nowak</Surname>
        <ProductOwner>false</ProductOwner>
    </Client>
</ClientList>
```

Comment: Shouldn’t your Number tag be before closing Client tag?

Comment: @KeshavGarg If I place `Number` tag before closing `ClientList` tag it works, but according to requirements `Number` tag should be after it, that's a problem.

Comment: @Viola, according to XML standard, you can not have multiple root tags. That way, you should place 'Number' tag inside 'ClientList' root tag or introduce new root tag that is wrapping both 'ClientList' and 'Number'. Otherwise, your XML is not well-formed.

Comment: @YurySchkatula  Ok, how can I 'introduce new root tag that is wrapping both 'ClientList' and 'Number'? I think it could be the decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as an answer to your request in comments (how can I 'introduce new root tag that is wrapping both 'ClientList' and 'Number').

Once trying your XSLT "as-is" there is an error dumped out:

```
Line:   12
Column: 2
Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document.
```

Once we add outer root tag, the stylesheet should be amended like that:

```
...
<xsl:template match="/">
<new-root> <- open new root tag here
<ClientList>
...
</Number>

</new-root> <- and close it there
</xsl:template>
...
```

Comment: I don't understand the difference between my tag <ClientList> and yours <new-root>. How should I change the other part of my XSL file?

Comment: You should insert new root before. Let me amend the example with more details.